# SVG Symbol animate not working with Safari

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, symbols

I'm currently struggling with a SVG.
Right now, I'm trying to display an animated SVG in my webpage. In order to do it, I just put the svg code at the end of the body, and used the html tag "use" to embed my SVG (which contains a symbol).
Here is my SVG code :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#7A5FFF">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#05FFA3; #45CAFC; #7873F5; #FC6262; #05FFA3;" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
   </stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01FF89">
    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#2096FF; #303F9F; #FF6EC4; #FFD86F; #2096FF;" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
   </stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <symbol x="0px" y="0px" width="308px" height="308px" viewBox="0 0 308 308" id="svg-logo">
  <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="150" fill="url(#linearGradient)" />
 </symbol>
</svg>
```

And here is the way I embed it in my page :

```
<svg class="star">
 <use xlink:href="#svg-logo">
</svg>
```

It works fine, except on safari. The linear gradient animation is completely broken, and looks like this :
[image: Broken Svg Safari]

Comment: I suspect you should really be raising this here: https://bugs.webkit.org